# I want to use scrollTo

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I work on a project in React Native and I would like to set my `ScrollView` position. So I search and I found we should do this with `scrollTo` but I have an error:

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTo' of undefined
> ```

My code:

```
export default class Index_calendar extends Component {
 componentDidMount() {
   const _scrollView = this.scrollView;
   _scrollView.scrollTo({x: 100});
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <ScrollView ref={scrollView => this.scrollView = scrollView}>
       {this.renderCalandar()}
     </ScrollView>
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars/issues/196 Hopefully this is helpful

Comment: `scrollTo` is part of the [Window API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `InteractionManager` to solve this issue.
For instance

`InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => this.scroll.current.scrollTo({ x }));`

Comment: Could it be because you use Animated.Scroll? Then that would be scroll.current.getNode().scrollTo

Answer (score 3):

Why not just scrollTo in the render method?

```
export default class Index_calendar extends Component {
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.scrollView = null;
}
render() {
   return (
   <ScrollView ref={scrollView => {
       //Sometimes ref can be null so we check it. 
       if(scrollView !== null && this.scrollView !== scrollView){
           this.scrollView = scrollView
           scrollView.scrollTo({x: 100});
       }}>
       {this.renderCalandar()}
  </ScrollView>
 );
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution ! we need to use setTimeout like that :

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.scrollView.scrollTo({x: 100});
}, 1);
```

Comment: This solution won't work reliably. use `InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to make correct reference. But I suggest to init the reference and make it less error prone:

```
export default class Index_calendar extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.scrollView = null;
 }

 componentDidMount() {
   const _scrollView = this.scrollView;

   if (_scrollView) {
     _scrollView.scrollTo({x: 100});
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
    this.scrollRef.scrollTo({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      animated: true,
    });
  });
```

This worked for me to reset the scroll to top